# Android - Shared Element Transition TextView keeps original layout gravity setting

Tags: android, android-animation, shared-element-transition

I'm trying to do a shared element transition with a TextView between an item in a list, and it's detail view.

The transition itself is working correctly, the text and images are moving both to the details fragment, and back to the list to the correct locations.

The problem I'm having is the TextView on the list has left gravity, and the TextView on the detail has center gravity.  When the transition happens, it's keeping the left gravity of the original TextView.

It's only after I call requestLayout() in code or click on an actionable item on the screen, that the text centers itself which won't work. I've tried this with and without the onPreDrawListener where you use startPostponedEnterTransition and it's the same problem.

Is there something I need to specifically do so the transition goes to the correct centered location on the detail view immediately?

I don't quite have time to make a sample app of this happening, but I'll have time next week if it's needed.  I'm hoping there's just some weird flag that I don't know about and can't find that would resolve this.